# MySQL SELECT accounts by username and unencrypted password

Tags: mysql, authentication, encryption

I've been working on this for some time, and have found numerous details about creating account, but nothing solid on getting data from an account given the username and raw password. For this scenario, we're working with a Joomla server that handles all the web stuff, and a C# chat server created for various purposes.

For starters, Joomla uses a MD5(password)+":"+salt process for a 66 digit hashed password. Of course we don't expect the users to know the hashed password, so I'm trying to figure out how to acquire the row from the username and unencryped password.

I want to avoid pulling the password to the server, even if the user can't get direct access to the information. The more I try to research into this, the less likely it becomes.

Recent Attempts:

```
SELECT name, usertype FROM fnpolit2.llc_users WHERE username='userid' AND password='password';
SELECT name, usertype FROM fnpolit2.llc_users WHERE username='userid' AND password LIKE '%:%';
SELECT name, usertype FROM fnpolit2.llc_users WHERE username='userid' AND password LIKE (MD5('password')+':%');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your password is stored in db as md5(password:salt) then you can do a select for user with the username and password like this

```
SELECT name, usertype FROM fnpolit2.llc_users WHERE username='userid' AND password =(MD5(CONCAT('password',':','salt')));
```

you want a user with the matching username and password so you should be looking for equality not like 
and md5 is already broken so don't use it for production systems.

Comment: Is the salt seed stored in a table? I can't imagine how it would check for login details on a password encrypted along side a random set of digits without one.

Comment: Yes you have to store the salt in the database or compute it based on some properties which produces the same salt for a user all the time. How else would you do it?

Comment: been scanning the php documents in Joomla. I can't find the database/value of the salt/seed. found various functions used in the process of generating a password based on security and such, but each one requests the seed/salt from elsewhere.

Comment: i have no experience with joomla but i found this on the joomla forum 
may be it can help 
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2414813

Answer (score 0):

The syntax I was looking for was

```
SELECT name, usertype FROM fnpolit2.llc_users WHERE username='userid' AND password=(CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT('password','salt')),':','salt'));
```

The password is salted, and then the salt key is attached to the password. Means I either have to grab the password once off the database, or write a SQL function to authenticate.